# ubuntu bind reverse look up fails

Tags: ubuntu, bind, reverse-dns

When I test my reverse zone from local machine by host ip, it says it is ok. 1.2.3.4.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer host.domain.co. however when i use tools like mxtoolbox or dnsstuff i get these errors
`SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch`    .
this is my config in name.config

```
zone "domain.co" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/db.domain.co";
};

zone "3.2.1.in-addr.arpa" {
type master;
file "/etc/bind/zones/rev.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

this is the main zone

```
domain.co. IN SOA lnxhost.domain.co. root.domain.co. (
2008080906 ; serial
8H ; refresh
4H ; retry
4W ; expire
1D ; minimum
)

domain.co. IN NS lnxhost.domain.co.
domain.co. IN MX 10 lnxhost.domain.co.

$ORIGIN domain.co.
localhost IN A 127.0.0.1

; Set the hostnames in alphabetical order
lnxhost IN A 1.2.3.4
domain.co. IN TXT "v=spf1 a -all"
```

this is the reverse entry

```
; IP Address-to-Host DNS Pointers for the 192.168.0 subnet
@ IN SOA lnxhost.domain.co. root.domain.co. (
2008080906 ; serial
8H ; refresh
4H ; retry
4W ; expire
1D ; minimum
)

3.2.1.in-addr.arpa. IN NS lnxhost.domain.co.

233 IN PTR lnxhost.domain.co.
```

syslogs have these

```
Apr 1 13:19:01 lnxagelity named[1009]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Apr 1 13:19:01 lnxagelity named[1009]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Apr 1 13:19:01 lnxagelity named[1009]: /etc/bind/zones/rev.51.135.206.in-addr.arpa:2: no TTL specified; using SOA MINTTL instead
Apr 1 13:19:01 lnxagelity named[1009]: zone 1.2.3.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 2008080906
Apr 1 13:19:01 lnxagelity named[1009]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Apr 1 13:19:01 lnxagelity named[1009]: zone domain.co/IN: loaded serial 2008080906
Apr 1 13:19:01 lnxagelity named[1009]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Apr 1 13:19:01 lnxagelity named[1009]: managed-keys-zone ./IN: loaded serial 5
Apr 1 13:19:01 lnxagelity named[1009]: running
```

Why tools like mxtoolbox. dnsstuff, fail to do the reverse look up?

Any help would be appreciated. Just for the record, I have been researching this for about a week. Thanks

Hint. This server is configure to be a dns, and mail server. I am able to send and receive mails. Only the reverse fails

Comment: Are you authoritative for the reverse zone at one of the Regional Internet Registries, or do you lease IP addresses from a third-party ISP? If you don't know the answer, it is most likely the latter, and that is probably where your problem lies. Most small-to-medium-sized rigs are simply assigned an IP range from their ISP, and therefore do not have control for the reverse lookup zone delegated to them. Your ISP would need to make the reverse DNS record on your behalf, or delegate the zone to you to make the changes (again, that is unlikely to happen as you do not "own" the addresses per se).

Comment: Matthew Thanks for answering. I have a public ip. that comes from network solutions. My dns server is working just fine. I use mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx and it report that all records are in placed and so on. It is able to resolve the A, mx, etc. However it fails when it does the reverse lookup. When I do host 1.2.3.4 internally is resolves just ok. when I use external tools like the one above then it fails.  Matthew pls any hints I would make you my GOD. I've been trying for a week now and what it looks something simple is becoming a nightmare. Pls any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure your public IP comes from Network Solutions? That may be the place your domain is hosted... I've never heard of them acting as an ISP, but then I'm not in the US which is probably where their market would be. I highly suspect you are not in control of your reverse DNS zone, and you need to contact your ISP to have this record created. Figure out the ISP you lease your IP addresses from. They are the people who manage the DNS servers for the *reverse* zone (which is not linked to the forward zone for any domains you own, e.g. .com). They need to create the records for you.

Comment: Matthew I have control over it. I have my DNS server working just fine. Only the reverse lookup is not working I can't find any human logical reason for it. In case you need some other info pls ask and I'll post it here. I post the most relevant information at the beginning of my question. If u need more pls let me know and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For reverse lookups to work, your DNS server(s) need to be the authoritative DNS for the IP space in question.  You can generally only do this if you have PI (provider independent) IP space.

If you have PA (provider assigned) IP space, you will only be able to do this if your ISP delegates the authority to your DNS server(s), otherwise you will be dependent on them to provide reverse lookups (which some will not do).  In some cases, your ISP may be providing addresses out of space assigned to them from one of their upstream providers.

If you haven't gotten assignments directly from your regional registry (ARIN, RIPE, APNIC, etc), then you do not have PI addresses.  One way to test is to do a whois lookup for your IP network.  If you or your organization are not listed, then you will not be able to do reverse lookups without contacting your ISP.

If you do have PI space, you may not have established the authority of your DNS servers.  You can check by doing a "dig" on the network.  For instance with an IP address of a.b.c.d you can do "dig d.c.b.a.in-addr.arpa" and it should return the authoritative servers.

Comment: YLearn thanks. All tha you said is new to me. However when I do dig 4.3.2.in-addr-arpa it says authority 1. and it says it is found in my domain. This test works from the server itself. When I try this from my home computer it fails. when I do dig mydonain.co it says that authority 1. so I guess my server is the autorithy for this zone. Pls any other hints

Comment: Don't confuse authority for a domain with authority for an IP network, nor local authority versus global authority. Since the dig fails on another computer but works on your DNS server, what you are in effect doing is usurping authority locally.  If a DNS server has a configured zone locally, it won't go elsewhere to find answers.  You could configure a "google.com" zone on your server and point "www" to 1.2.3.4 and when doing lookups against your DNS you will resolve "www.google.com" to 1.2.3.4.  This does not mean that you have authority for "google.com" and it will not work anywhere else.

Comment: Ok. But then how do we explain that when I go here mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx and enter my domain it reports Pref  Hostname  IP Address  TTL  
10  lnxhost.mydomain.co  myip  7 days  Blacklist Check      SMTP Test. In other words my ip/domain is found from outside world. Dig only fails when reverse is perform. It is just the reverse lookup for emails that doesn't work. sorry the formatting

Comment: What is reported based on your DOMAIN authority has nothing to do with the NETWORK authority.  They are entirely separate issues.  Just because a domain points at an IP address does not mean that you have any control over the authority for that IP address or the network of which it is part.  Go to http://www.arin.net and enter your server IP address in the "Search whois" field in upper right corner.  This will return who has authority for that network.

Comment: Ylearn. Sorry I feel embarrased. I did that and I don't see anything related to my domain. What would you suggest. And I really apreciate your time and patients.

Comment: Don't feel embarrassed. It can be a confusing issue until you get your head around it. While you have registered the domain and have authority over it, someone else has registered the network and has authority over that.  They have allowed someone else (you or your provider or their provider, etc) to use it.  I saw in another comment that your web host appears to be Network Solutions.  You should open a ticket with them asking them to update the reverse lookup for the IP they have assigned for your use.  Not sure if they offer that as part of their service, but you can't do it on your own.

Comment: I will contact them to see if I can get any help. Thank u very much. It is ok to contact you if any other final question? If so how?

Comment: If you had a new question, I would suggest posting it as such.  There are many knowledgeable people here who can help if needed and you may get a faster response that way.